# With NSProgress, are the completion handlers intended for the UI or the download controller?

Tags: objective-c, design-patterns

I am using [NSProgress](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSProgress_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to communicate the progress of file downloads in my iOS app.
It is a very general-purpose class and I'm a bit scared of its inherent power, especially with the two completion handling properties. There is one for dealing with canceling, and one for pausing (but none for completion, which is perhaps a hit…)

What are these handlers intended for? The code that does the download could put logic in these to deal with user-originated cancels and pauses. However, there is nothing stopping a client to overwrite the handlers with UI code.

So, is it intended for the UI? I am not sure how this is a helpful patterns, since the UI would be originating the cancel or pause anyway. Also, if you are using the progress object to simultaneously present progress across multiple UI elements (the way it is used in MacOS), the different UI elements would potentially all want its own completion handler.

Using the handlers to communicate user actions back to the download controller seems the most useful pattern, but then I would have expected the handler to be set up at initialization and then remain read-only.

What am I missing here?

(P.S. For now I am simply not going to use those handlers and rely on KVO. However, I have an itchy feeling that I am missing out on some fundamental idea behind the class)

Comment: That looks like a private class to me, are you sure you want to use it?

Comment: It is not private. See [Apple's developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSProgress_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: My bad, I had no idea that existed.

Comment: From NSHipster's [post on iOS7](http://nshipster.com/ios7/):"\[NSProgress\] can specify handlers for pausing and canceling, which then forward onto the operation actually doing the work"

Comment: Interestingly, the only code sample available for iOS that uses NSProgress ([MultipeerGroupChat](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MultipeerGroupChat/Listings/AdhocGroupChat_ProgressObserver_h.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013691-AdhocGroupChat_ProgressObserver_h-DontLinkElementID_11)) "uses Key Value Observeration (KVO) to monitor the NSProgress for Multipeer Connectivity API resource sending/receiving completion progress (or cancellation)" rather than the handlers

Comment: If you're just trying to download some files, you could give [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) a shot, it has progress handlers and is specifically built for networking.

Comment: @Ian you are quite right that AFNetworking will solve most problems. My question, however, was about programming style with regards to this new class. I find that it is not always obvious when using blocks will simplify code or create future issues.

Comment: @ChristianHeidarson You haven't accepted any answer, did mine help at all?

Comment: @jamesmoschou yes, it did! (better late than never, i hope you'll agree)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the key that you are missing is that the `NSProgress` class is designed to be used as a tree of progress objects. Further this tree is created implicitly with child progress objects not needing to be aware that they are attached to a parent, this is where it's real power comes from.

I found the OS X Foundation Release Notes much more helpful than the class reference for `NSProgress`:

https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/releasenotes/Foundation/RN-Foundation/index.html

The reason why it seems handlers can be used for both UI controller logic and data controller logic is that when you construct a parent-child hierarchy, you have two sets of handlers that can be used for both. The parent's handlers would be set at the UI controller level (the 'consumer' of the progress), and the child's handlers would be set by the data controller (the 'provider').

Since the relationship can be created implicitly using `becomeCurrentWithPendingUnitCount:` the child progress object will be insulated from parent, which would alleviate your concern about clients overwriting any data-level handlers with their own.

Calling `pause` or `cancel` on a progress object will propagate that call down the tree, calling any handlers on the way.

An example:

```
// UI controller level, probably a UIViewController subclass.
- (void)handleDoSomethingButtonTapped:(UIButton *)sender
{
    self.progressThatWeObserve =
        [NSProgress progressWithTotalUnitCount:100]; // 100 is arbitrary
    self.progressThatWeObserve.pausingHandler = ^{
        // Update UI, reflect paused state ...
    };

    [self.progressThatWeObserve becomeCurrentWithPendingUnitCount:100];
    [self.dataController doSomethingInBackgroundWithCompletionHandler:^{
        // Update UI, remove from view ...
    }];
    [self.progressThatWeObserve resignCurrent];
}

// Data controller level, a SomethingManager class maybe.
- (void)doSomethingInBackgroundWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void)completionHandler
{
    self.progressThatWeManipulate =
        [NSProgress progressWithTotalUnitCount:289234]; // e.g. bytes to upload
    self.progressThatWeManipulate.pausingHandler = ^{
        // Actually suspend the network operation ...
    };

    dispath_async(self.workerQueue, ^{
        // Periodically update progress
    });
}
```

Please note I haven't actually done any of this, it is all theory from reading documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use those blocks for anything you want.  Specifically, if you want to do something to the UI you should make sure to do it on the main thread as noted in the "special considerations" section of the documentation, "The cancellation handler may be invoked on any queue. If you must do work on a specific queue, you should dispatch to that queue from within the cancellation handler block."  So for UI you would use:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // Do work on UI
});
```

The completion handler pattern is common for dealing with tasks that are 'always' done in the background; I/O tasks such as downloading a file from a server.  In this case though it is also useful to define a single handler for pausing and cancelling because there might be many events within your application that invoke the pause: or cancel: methods on the NSProgress instance.

Comment: It's the fact that I *can* use them for whatever I want that confuses me. However, I think you are correct in that since these are blocks that will likely be called in the background, they are not intended for UI code. That is, the download logic code would set the handlers, and the UI code would never mess with those handlers.

Comment: Right, so if you want to do work on the UI within those blocks, you should put it on the main thread (the only place you should ever mess with the UI), as in my answer.